# Is there a way to break out from a inner for loop but not outer for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am very new to python Please help.
how can I break from a inner for loop in a nested for loop in python. I tried the 'break' statement but it is exiting from both for loops and I want to exit from just inner for loop.  Actually I am trying to find subarray (of a given array) with certain sum.

```
def subArraySum(A,Sum):
    curr_sum = A[0]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
            if curr_sum == Sum:
                return [i,j]
            if curr_sum>Sum or j==len(A):
                break
            curr_sum = curr_sum+A[j]
    return [-1]



N = int(input())
Sum = int(input())

A = list(map(int,input().split()))

ans = subArraySum(A, Sum)
for i in ans:
    print(i, end='')
print()
```

Comment: Show your code, so we can point out where you went wrong.

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: simply `break` is sufficient, but often this is a good case for a function!

Comment: This code does not have a `break` ...

Comment: I copy paste here wrong code. I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if j == 3:
            break
        print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
3 0
3 1
3 2
4 0
4 1
4 2
```